# angular2 unit test pass data to input from spec

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine

I have declared a component like this

```
export class Component {

  private selectedFieldType: string;
  private enableAddCheck: boolean = false;

  @Input('itemX') item;
}
```

and i have a html for two binding like this

```
Field : <input [(ngModel)]="item.fieldLabel" type="text" class="input-bars">
```

So i have created the unit testing code like this to check the two way binding like this

```
beforeEach(async(() => {


    // refine the test module by declaring the test component
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule ],
      declarations: [Component , DND_DIRECTIVES],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true },
         DND_PROVIDERS ]
    })

    // create component and test fixture
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component );

    // get test component from the fixture
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;



  }));

  it('To check fieldLabel to way binding from inputbox to data', () => {

    comp.item = {
      fieldLabel: 'text'
    };


    fixture.detectChanges();

    let fieldTypeInput: HTMLInputElement;

    const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));

    fieldTypeInput = input[0].nativeElement;
    fieldTypeInput.value = 'field';

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(comp.item.fieldLabel).toBe('field');

  });
```

But it's giving 'fieldLabel' undefined error for me.

How to pass the data to @input in my component through the unit test??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// refine the test module by declaring the test component
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule ],
      declarations: [Component , DND_DIRECTIVES],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
         DND_PROVIDERS ]
    })
```

the error was in ComponentFixtureAutoDetect. because it's mentioned as a provider it doesn't detect the change when data is passed through the instance. so we have to manually detect changes using DetectChanges() function